# Msbuild ignoring build errors

Tags: msbuild, nunit, jenkins-pipeline, msbuild-task, dotcover

### Context

I have a task integration testing and code coverage which I execute in my jenkins pipeline.

The tools used is **dotcover** and **Nunit**.

Nunit is executed throught dotcover during the integration test build when the configuration is *Integration*.

### Problem

When I execute the configuration *Integration* in **visual studio** with some tests in error, then the build failed, everything are ok, but when the same configuration are executed with **msbuild**, it doesn't return any error code then jenkins pipelin doesn't fail.

The situation put us in delicate way because we can't trust our build pipeline anymore.

I looking for a solution on web for some days and I still on the same point, it's why I asking for your help here.

Thank you for helping.

### Files

#### jenkinsfile

```
node('BUILD_PROJECT') {
    stage ('Checkout')
    {
        checkout scm
    }

    stage ('Build')
    {
        bat '"C:/Program Files (x86)/NuGet/nuget.exe" restore -NonInteractive MySolution.sln'
        bat "\"C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/BuildTools/MSBuild/15.0/Bin/MSBuild.exe\" /p:Configuration=Release;AssemblyVersion=0.1.0.${env.BUILD_NUMBER} /maxcpucount:8 MySolution.sln"
    }

    stage ('Integration')
    {
        bat "\"C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/BuildTools/MSBuild/15.0/Bin/MSBuild.exe\" /p:Configuration=Integration /maxcpucount:8 MySolution.sln"
    }

    stage ('Publish Coverage')
    {
         publishHTML target: [
            allowMissing: false,
            alwaysLinkToLastBuild: false,
            keepAll: true,
            reportDir: 'Solution/IntegrationProject/bin/Integration/TestResult',
            reportFiles: 'ProjectCoverageReport.html',
            reportName: 'Project Coverage Report'
          ]
    }

    stage ('Setup')
    {
    bat "\"C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/BuildTools/MSBuild/15.0/Bin/MSBuild.exe\" /p:Configuration=Setup;Platform=x86;AssemblyVersion=0.1.0.${env.BUILD_NUMBER} /maxcpucount:8 MySolution.sln"
    }

    stage ('Archive')
    {
        archiveArtifacts artifacts: 'Solution/SetupProject/bin/x86/Setup/MySetup.exe'
    }
}
```

#### In IntegrationProject.csproj

```
<Target Name="CoverageReport" AfterTargets="CopySqlFiles" Condition="$(Configuration) == Integration">
    <Exec Command="..\packages\JetBrains.dotCover.CommandLineTools.2018.1.3\tools\dotCover.exe analyse /TargetExecutable=..\packages\NUnit.ConsoleRunner.3.8.0\tools\nunit3-console.exe /ReturnTargetExitCode /TargetArguments=&quot;$(TargetPath)&quot; /Filters=-:nunit.framework;-:IntegrationProjectTest;-:type=MyNamespace.View.*;-:type=*Test /TargetWorkingDir=$(TargetDir) /Output=$(TargetDir)\TestResult\MyCoverageReport.html /ReportType=HTML" />
</Target>
```

Comment: When you create a binary log (`-bl` argument to Msbuild), does it show your project and target being executed? I suggest you use [MSBuild Structured Log Viewer](http://msbuildlog.com) to dig into this.

Comment: Thank you for the tool i'll take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to make use of the dotcover parameter **[ReturnTargetExitCode](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/dotcover/dotCover__Console_Runner_Commands.html)** to get the return code from nunit.

```
<Target Name="CoverageReport" AfterTargets="CopySqlFiles" Condition="$(Configuration) == Integration">
    <Exec Command="..\packages\JetBrains.dotCover.CommandLineTools.2018.1.3\tools\dotCover.exe analyse ^
        /TargetExecutable=..\packages\NUnit.ConsoleRunner.3.8.0\tools\nunit3-console.exe ^
        /ReturnTargetExitCode ^
        /TargetArguments=&quot;$(TargetPath)&quot; ^
        /Filters=-:nunit.framework;-:IntegrationProjectTest;-:type=MyNamespace.View.*;-:type=*Test ^
        /TargetWorkingDir=$(TargetDir) ^
        /Output=$(TargetDir)\TestResult\MyCoverageReport.html ^
        /ReportType=HTML
        /ReturnTargetExitCode">
      <Output TaskParameter="ExitCode" PropertyName="DotCoverExitCode" />
    </Exec>

    <Message Text="Unit Tests Failed!" Condition="$(DotCoverExitCode) != '0'"/>  

</Target>
```

Comment: Hello, your answer fix my problem, I used ReturnTargetExitCode, this parameter is in my task but I didn't used <Output /> then with this it's ok now.

Thank you & regards